# Swagger Core Jersey 2.X with ResourceConfig

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, swagger-2.0

I am trying to add swagger to my application.

I am following this guide https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-Jersey-2.X-Project-Setup-1.5#using-a-custom-application-subclass

but I have Jersey configured as ResourceConfig like this:

```
    @ApplicationPath("/resources/api")
     public class ApiApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public ApiApplication() {
        super(MultiPartFeature.class);
        packages("my.rest.resources");
        register(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource.class);
        register(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers.class);

        BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
        beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.2");
        beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[]{"http"});
        beanConfig.setHost("localhost:8080");
        beanConfig.setBasePath("/resources/api");
        beanConfig.setResourcePackage("my.rest.resources");
        beanConfig.setScan(true);
    }
  }
```

Is this correct?

There is no swagger.json generated.

According to my understanding swagger files should be on the following link http://localhost/api/api-docs/swagger.json

### Updated:

Changed BasePath to resources/api

I also get the following exception in tomcat log:

```
    SEVERE: Servlet /XXXXXX threw load() exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.reflections.util.ClasspathHelper.forPackage(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Ljava/util/Collection;
    at io.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig.classes(BeanConfig.java:189)
    at io.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig.setScan(BeanConfig.java:168)
    at my.rest.resources.apps.ApiApplication.<init>(ApiApplication.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
```

Comment: It looks like you have the wrong version of the org.reflections dependency. I suggest you use some sort of dependency management utility to get the correct versions of your dependencies, such as maven.

Comment: I am using maven and I have only included <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>   <version>1.5.0</version>

Comment: That was unexpected. You can try to run mvn dependency:tree and see if you have any conflicting versions with regards to org.reflections:reflections.

Comment: I have only reflections 0.9.9 as a compile dependecy listed in my project.

Comment: Well then. If you haven't added a different version to the lib folder of your tomcat, then I'm out of ideas.

Comment: with updating swagger-jersey2-jaxrs to 1.5.4 the problem is gone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The [`ApiListingResource`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/master/modules/swagger-jaxrs/src/main/java/io/swagger/jaxrs/listing/ApiListingResource.java#L40) (where the swagger data comes from), is nothing more than another JAX-RS (Jersey) resource class.

   ```
   @Path("/")
   public class ApiListingResource {
       ...
       @GET
       ...
       @Path("/swagger.{type:json|yaml}")
       public Response getListing(..) {...}
       ...
   }
   ```

   So the resource path would be the base `@ApplicationPath("/resources/api")` and the swagger resource path `/swagger.json`. So you would need to access `/resources/api/swagger.json`.
2. You need to fix your base path in the `BeanConfig`. This base path is used to create the URLs for swagger UI. Using the base path `"/api"` means the URL data will cause the UI to access `/api/yourresource` which doesn't exist. The base path should be a combination of the servlet context (which I'm guessing in your case is none) and the Jersey base path (which is `/resources/api`). So set `BeanConfig` base path to `"/resources/api"`

Comment: Show your dependencies. It's probably a dependency issue

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.reflections.util.ClasspathHelper.forPackage(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Ljava/util/Collection;
    at io.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig.classes(BeanConfig.java:189)
    at io.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig.setScan(BeanConfig.java:168)
    at my.rest.resources.apps.ApiApplication.(ApiApplication.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

By the above stacktrace, its been observed as below:

Actually you are using Jersey1.x supported jar i.e reflections-0.9.9-RC1.jar, so add the Jersey 2.x supported jar reflections-0.9.9.jar to your libs folder or classpath. That will resolve the above issue